# Syntax to select several 'Locations' in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm blocking all access to files on

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
    Allow from None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

With except to the following two files

```
<Location /subdir/file.php>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Location>


<Location /subdir2/file2.php>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Location>
```

Is there any way I can allow access to both these files from the same directive like

```
<Location /subdir/file.php, /subdir2/file2.php>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Location>
```

So I don't need to create a new `<Location>` directive for each file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LocationMatch "^/subdir/(file\.php|file2\.php)$">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Location>
```